# Solution to PDE given by $u_{x}^{2}u_{xx}+2u_{x}u_{y}u_{xy}+u_{y}^{2}u_{yy}=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I am attempting to solve this problem from *Partial Differential Equations* 2nd Edition, by Evans, from Chapter 4. The issue is that I am not sure how to get past a certain point:

Use separation of variables to find a nontrivial solution of $u$ of the PDE

$$u_{x}^{2}u_{xx}+2u_{x}u_{y}u_{xy}+u_{y}^{2}u_{yy}=0$$

I started by assuming the solution $u$ is given by $u(x,y)=w(x)v(y)$. Then we have

$$u_{x} = w'(x)v(y)$$
$$u_{y} = w(x)v'(y)$$
$$u_{xx} = w''(x)v(y)$$
$$u_{yy} = w(x)v''(y)$$
$$u_{xy} = w'(x)v'(y)$$

So the equation may be rewritten (after some algebraic manipulation) as

$$\frac{(w')^{2}w''}{w^{3}}+\frac{2(w')^{2}(v')^{2}}{w^{2}v^{2}}+\frac{(v')^{2}v''}{v^{3}}=0$$

I've tried multiple things from here but each thing gives me a dead-end. Any hints as to what to do here? I imagine it may have to do with rewriting some of these terms as differentials and then using a factoring, but I am not seeing it. Perhaps I am not even in the right ballpark. I'd love some help with this.

EDIT: The solution is obtained upon assuming $u(x,y)=w(x)+v(y)$ rather than $u(x,y)=w(x)\cdot v(y)$. Whereupon the middle term of the PDE vanishes and we obtain the equation

$$(w')^{2}w'' + (v')^{2}v''=0$$

This is solved by noting that $(w')^{2}w''=-(v')^{2}v''=constant$ and using integration to find the solution.

Comment: The fact that these are sort of homogenous in $u$ makes me want to write $u(x,y)=e^{f(x,y)}.$  Not sure that helps, though. Maybe a mix of your approach, with $u(x,y)=e^{w(x)+v(y)}.$ But that approach, assuming $u(x,y)=w(x)v(y),$ seems best when the equation is linear.

Comment: Where did the $2$ go in your manipulation? Seems like you should still get a $2$ coefficient for the middle term.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews a minor typo, good catch. I'll give your suggestion a try and see if it yields anything meaningful.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I have something by using the additive separation $u(x,y)=w(x)+v(y)$ instead. I will post my results as soon as I come up with a possible solution.

Comment: Yeah, $u(x,y)=w(x)+v(y)$ gives $u_{xy}=0,$ so the middle term vanishes, and you get $(w')^2w''+(v')^2v'',$ but this just gives constants. So $(v')^2v''=c$ must be a constant, and $(v')^3=3cy +d$ or $v'=\sqrt[3]{3cy+d}$ or $v=\frac{1}{4c}(3cx+d)^{4/3}+b.$

Comment: Similarly, $w=\frac{-1}{4c}(-3cx+d')^{4/3}+b'.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews those are the same results I obtained. That was fun.

Comment: These won't be all results, I suspect. And you can't linearly combine different $u$ to get a new solution, so this only finds a subset of solutions.

Comment: Look to theorem 9 in the paper by Gunnar Aronsson in Arkiv For Mathematik Band 7 nr 28 from 12 April 1967 titled "On the partial differential equation $u_x^2 u_{xx} + 2 u_x u_y u_{xy} + u_y^2 u_{yy}$". The only global solutions to this equation are linear.

Comment: One obvious solution is exp(x+iy).